Can't recognize audio file in Flask backend
I am having difficulty processing an audio blob I am sending to a Flask backend. I want to process the blob into a mel-spectrogram using librosa/pydub, but I get the following errors:
ERROR:root:Librosa error processing <_io.BytesIO object at 0x3219eff60>: Error opening <_io.BytesIO object at 0x3219eff60>: Format not recognised.
ERROR:root:Pydub error processing <_io.BytesIO object at 0x3219eff60>: Decoding failed. ffmpeg returned error code: 183
I use [this voice recorder library][1] to record audio on my front end, using the following code to package my blob. This is called from the prop onAudioDownload:
const onAudioDownload = (blob) => {
    console.log('audio ended')
    console.log(typeof(blob))

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', new Blob([blob], { type: 'audio/wav' }));

    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/predictTest', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log('Success:', data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      });
  };

This is the code to process the audio snippet where the blob is passed as song:
def process_audio(song):

    sr=16000
    n_mels=128
    n_fft=2048
    hop_length=512

    slice_length = 911

    print(song)
    print('Loading song...')
try:
        y, sr = librosa.load(song, sr=sr)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Librosa error processing {song}: {e}")
        # Fallback: Use pydub to decode the MP3 file
        try:
            audio = AudioSegment.from_file(song)
            y = np.array(audio.get_array_of_samples())
            sr = audio.frame_rate
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Pydub error processing {song}: {e}")

Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.
[1]: https://github.com/AbreezaSaleem/react-voice-recorder-player
